# Java SE, корректная запись строки байтовых символов в байтовый массив

Tags: java

Имеется Строка `String Packet` в которой записываетются данные а-ля FA0023CC и массив `byte[] P = new byte[Packet.length()/2]`в который нужно загнать данные по типу 0xFA 0x00 0x23 0xCC
Пишу байты таким способом:

```
P[i]= (byte)  ((Character.digit(Packet.charAt(i*2), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(Packet.charAt(i*2+1), 16));
```

где i - номер байта, всё считывается корректно пока не сталкиваюсь с байтами больше 7F, начиная с 80 они почему то становятся отрицательтными и идут в обратную сторону (если переводить 0х80, 0х81, 0х82 в int, то будет не 128, 129, 130, а -128, -127, -126 и т.д.)

Comment: Все правильно - двоичные числа с единицой на первой позиции в информатике интерпретируются как отрицательные. Вам бы помог тип ``unsigned byte``, но в яве такого нет. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Можно ли исправить интерпретирование, чтобы, например корректно работало сравнение `if (P[i]==0xFF)`, если считалась строка FF, а то сейчас сравнение корректно работает только с числами по 7F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку вы сравниваете тип `byte` с типом `int`, то для чисел больше 127 возникает следующая проблема - несмотря на внешнюю похожесть, это разные числа:

- число FF типа `byte` это -1 (двоичное представление - `11111111`).
- число FF типа `int` (тип чисел по умолчанию) это 255 (двоичное представление - `24нуля11111111`).

Решить проблему можно двумя способами:

1. Конвертировать `byte` в `int`, т.е. дописать спереди 24 нуля. В данном случае особого смысла нет, потому что нас интересуют только отрицательные числа, а с ними как раз и будет заморока.
2. Конвертировать `int` в `byte` (т.е. попросту отбросить первые 24 нуля). Вот так:

   `(P[i] == (byte) 0xFF)`

Comment: Спасибо, решил 2-м способом